# How to track where the control has dropped in the view in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to drag a textView and drop it on the layouts below of my grid layout. I unable to track where my textview is getting dropped and print the position of it. Then i want to replace that textview with the empty button/textview.

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{
    public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent motionEvent){
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy");
            clipBoard.setPrimaryClip(data);
            String clipString = clipBoard.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(clipString);
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v,DragEvent event){
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action){
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            View view  = (View) event.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)v;
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println(tagTextIndex);
            ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
            String dragData = (String)item.getText();
            Toast.makeText(Free_play.this, "Dragged item is:"+dragData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            view.invalidate();

            break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```